# Brush zooming in X and Y in Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

In Vega-lite, is it possible to zoom in to a plot with a brush in the X and Y direction at the same time? 
Using this example as a base:
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_overview_detail.html

I tried encoding the Y, but I'm not sure how to point `"scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush"}}` in the Y axis direction.

[unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUp0S.png)

If not, is it possible to achieve similar results with the `"bind": "scales"`? The goal is to have a "key-map" of the chart with a zoom-in, and a small box showing where the zoom is on the broader time-series.

Code I've been trying with that example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "vconcat": [{
    "width": 480,
    "mark": "area",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "field": "date",
        "type": "temporal",
        "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush"}},
        "axis": {"title": ""}
      },
      "y": {"field": "price", 
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush"}}
}
    }
  }, {
    "width": 480,
    "height": 60,
    "mark": "area",
    "selection": {
      "brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x","y"]}
    },
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "field": "date",
        "type": "temporal"
      },
      "y": {
        "field": "price",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
      }
    }
  }]
}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the `field` or the `encoding` within the domain; for example:

```
"domain": {"selection": "brush", "encoding": "y"}
```

Putting this into your example looks like this ([view live](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvR9CAVgAMtuvFgVIAX3URIFeMvg6zANoaEKAQYVAA7oyaLGbSABy2HuFQGEYA1maQ6EbImMnhkMhKPpqMStRmoSmeAB5VwTVQAGaMyGKaWdp4yGqNNZB4AJ6EvTiDaITcRuimBU2QCLNjYAaa3BjlVYvtyPB4PCrj7EassIhqUMWl5ZXj9a7u-SnZtYyw2wd4YiuQbs8QJ5NKBDBrAzytdqdcaEIyMeC9eYDYajLIAR1Y6CUXx0jCofXBUCWP22602R1WOx++0OWROZwuqiuJW4ZQqWVBjwBYFcz154SBYWqhSiMQuOASSWekBQjGo+DMADYpQM0plxjk8gSXrBdjTlNt6edPiNfuUekYKLNLkUWWzqB8cAFIPUmZBQQBdR5I5k3dn6bku7aQjpdHSIqAo349VBTGamQUDUEBwmQEPQqCw+GI7meKPozHY5i4-E+wroN6OykHeDpADC3FY2LMAGY3dQ4RnmrNdfymn2BY0+x6QK4gA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush", "encoding": "x"}},
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush", "encoding": "y"}}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 480,
      "height": 60,
      "mark": "area",
      "selection": {"brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x", "y"]}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: How would one go about achieving the same in-place, with animation, in one display ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in-place", "with animation" or "in one display". Perhaps you can ask a new question clarifying what you're trying to do?

Comment: I believe @BuZz means how to do it with only one chart, no range selector chart.  The multiple redraws as the scale changes with each mouse change looks like animation.